# Overlaps with VLANS

Tags: cisco, vlan, ip, subnet, packet-tracer

[image: Topology]

This's problem

`SW_R2(config)#int vlan 2
SW_R2(config-if)#ip addr 172.16.0.129 255.255.255.240
SW_R2(config-if)#int vlan 3
SW_R2(config-if)#ip addr 172.16.0.145 255.255.255.224
% 172.16.0.128 overlaps with Vlan2
SW_R2(config-if)#`

I'm using a Switch Layer 3, setting up Ip address in three Vlans.

172.16.0.128/29 and 172.16.0.144/27 are in differents subnets, I tested that address in a Router, setting in a FastEthernet Interface, and works!

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
!

interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan2
 ip address 172.16.0.129 255.255.255.240
!
interface Vlan3
 no ip address
```

I can't SEE where is my error, Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies in your subnets

172.16.0.145 with subnet mask 255.255.255.224 give you a network 172.16.0.128/27

The network you set on VLAN 2 is a subnet of the one you try to set on VLAN3 , so the overlap.

EDIT in response to the comment

The network 172.16.0.128/27 can be subnetted in 2 networks

- 172.16.0.128/28
- 172.16.0.144/28

So you can use those two subnets on VLAN2 and VLAN3 but not the original network and one of its subnet.

Change your subnet mask to 255.255.255.240 and you will have no overlap.

If you need a bigger subnet (for more than 14 hosts) then you need to use the next-available /27 network which is 172.16.0.160/27 (I.E. 172.16.0.160 with subnet mask 255.255.255.224)

Edit 2 in response to other comment

to subnet the /26 to a /27 plus two /28 you can use

- 172.16.0.128/28
- 172.16.0.144/28
- 172.16.0.160/27

or

- 172.16.0.128/27
- 172.16.0.160/28
- 172.16.0.176/28

Note that due to the network address and the broadcast address a /28 allows 14 hosts (including the one that will be used as gateway) and a /27 allows 30.

Comment: I Thought that setting a mask /28 (16 hosts) on VLAN 2, my next network would be 172.16.0.144, being VLAN 2 is 172.16.0.128/28

Comment: your next network would be 172.16.0.144/28, not /27. I edited the answer in response to this.

Comment: Before I change my mask to `255.255.255.240` WORTH! But I'm starting to understand, well begin with a issue ok? I've a Addr Block `172.16.0.128/26` 
I've to subnet on Three VLAN. VLAN 2 (16 Hosts) `/28` VLAN 3 (32 Hosts)  `/27` what remain I get on VLAN 4.. How do I do it?

Comment: A /26 can be subnetted to two /27, each /27 can be subnetted to two /28. So you can either user 3 networks /28 (and there will a /28 left available) or two /28 and one /27 (in this case the entire /26 is used).

Comment: I thinking `172.16.0.128/28` `172.16.0.144/27` `172.16.0.172/28`, but that is impossible I think

Comment: see edit 2 in my response

Answer (score 1):

Your int vlan 3 IP address falls in a subnetwork of 172.16.0.128/27 with possible host range of 172.16.0.129-172.16.0.159.
It definetely overlapps with int vlan 2 IP address you've assigned

Comment: But If I define VLAN 2 with Address 172.16.0.129 255.255.255.240, The Router knows the possible host range `172.16.0.130 - 172.16.0.142`, right?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct.  To find a subnet address of any IP address, mask the given address with the mask.  This means that any subnet with a /27 (32-bit address - 27-bit mask = 5 addreess bits, 2^5=32) must start at a multiple of 32.  The 144 address is not a multiple of 32.

In any such question, it helps to do it in binary.  Just AND the address with the mask to get the subnet.